# module 'pandas' has no attribute 'json_normalize'

Tags: python, pandas, raspberry-pi

I am trying to run a python program on a raspberry pi. The program uses the pandas library including the 'json_normalize' function. I have tried importing pandas with import pandas, and from pandas.io.json import json_normalize but I still get the error. I am using pandas version 0.23.3. Is it just a version problem or is there something else?

Comment: yes. version problem. `.json_normalize()` is with 0.25.0,  upgrade your pandas. Or use `from pandas.io.json import json_normalize`

Comment: i use version `1.4.2` and it works fine...  seems that you are quite a few versions back.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with Pandas 0.23.

but, You still can run it with pandas 0.22

check this issue open for this [problem](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/21158)